# Webpack SCSS Image URL Links Broken on Nested Routes

Tags: sass, webpack, react-router, babeljs, sass-loader

Here is my directory structure:

```
- public
- src
  - app.js
  - assets
    - images
      - logo-b-green.png 
    - stylesheets
      - nav.scss
```

And:

```javascript
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: './public',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
      },
      {
          test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
          loader: 'file?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        loader: "file-loader?name=images/img-[hash:6].[ext]"
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.json']
  }
};
```

And:

```css
/* nav.scss */

#nav-logo {
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: url('../images/logo-b-green.png');
  float: left;
  margin: 16px 0 0 23px;
}
```

When loading single level routes my image links work correctly.

For example at `/search` the image link is rendered as `url(images/img-75fa3d.png)` and works.

However, if I go to a nested route (via React Router), e.g. `/properties/1` the image link is the same and cannot find the correct image location as it's a relative link: `url(images/img-75fa3d.png)`.

The image from this example is `logo-b-green.png`.

EDIT:

I added the `publicPath` to the `output` section and it worked, now the urls go the root. Can someone confirm that this is the correct way to handle this?

```javascript
output: {
 path: './public',
 filename: 'bundle.js',
 publicPath: '/'
}, ...
```

Comment: I was going to suggest setting `publicPath`, so yeah. AFAIK, it's used to prefix URL's to resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the `publicPath` to the `output` section and it worked, now the urls go the root.

```javascript
output: {
 path: './public',
 filename: 'bundle.js',
 publicPath: '/'
}, ...
```